# Substitute for querySelectorAll in Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Is there a substitute for querySelectorAll in Polymer?

I like to do many stuff programmatically and for single elements I use:

```dart
ButtonElement b2 = $["b2"];
```

But if I want to get several radiobuttons, I can't use the usual

```dart
List<InputElement> radios = querySelectorAll("[name='func']");
radios.forEach((f) {
  f.onClick.listen((e) => changeFunction(f,e));
});
```

Should I be doing it in a different way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ShadowRoot` (which extends `DocumentFragment`), and `Element` both have `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` that are scoped properly.

For a custom element, which you use depends on whether you want to query the light or shadow DOM, but since you are using `$[]`, you probably want to use the shadow root.

Try this:

```dart
List<InputElement> radios = shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("[name='func']");
```

Comment: for browsers that does not supports parts of WebComponents specs or if you're using Shady DOM, I do a check like this: 


```(this.shadowRoot) ? this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.foo') : this.querySelectorAll('.foo');```

Comment: Don't do that because you might pick up light DOM elements. Use `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.foo')`